# How to install packages on RHEL6.6 VM on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 VM on Bluemix Virtual Machines BETA.

How do I install a package using yum? For example, git is missing.

I get the message:

This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without registering a Red Hat Enterprise Linux license, you're not going to be able to install anything.

If you're looking for a no-cost solution that is very much similar to RHEL, I suggest using CentOS.

Comment: It is important to note that any VM image which requires a license, it is your responsibility as a user to acquire the license and comply with the terms of that license.  See the important note about images in the documentation: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_default_images

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to use Red Hat OS,  you can replace the `yum` with CentOS version.
Here are the detail steps:

1. find CentOS mirror packages:

this is mirror packages I am using: [163](http://mirrors.163.com/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/)

2. find the rpm you need to re-install:

`rpm -qa | grep yum`

3. un-install the rpms of output of previous command

`[root@localhost ~]# rpm -e yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-10.el7.x86_64 --nodeps
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -e yum-3.4.3-125.el7.noarch --nodeps
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -e yum-rhn-plugin-2.0.1-5.el7.noarch --nodeps`

4. download reference rpms from your mirror system
5. install the rpm with command:

`rpm -ivh yum-*`

during the installation, system may shows some dependencies are necessary, like this:

`error: Failed dependencies:
        python-urlgrabber >= 3.10-8 is needed by yum-3.4.3-154.el7.centos.noarch`
 
you need to download reference dependency from mirror system and install them with command:

`rpm -Uvh python-urlgrabber-3.10-8.el7.noarch.rpm --nodeps`

6. replace the yum repo configuration file:

`rm /etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo
vim /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

edit the file with content of this file: http://mirrors.163.com/.help/CentOS6-Base-163.repo

7. update yum
   run 

   `yum clean all
   yum makecache`